# How to open external link in elementor Popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, popup, elementor

I am using elementor as a page builder and want to open external link in an elementor popup, i have been looking for solution so far i have not found much help, not sure if this is possible to open external link in elementor popup.

In my case i have `Book Now` link as part of my menu and i want click event to trigger popup to show external link with booking form to it example  `https://www.reserveout.com/en/rowidget?key=SUUWGPGUq4Aa96NVf&vi=140002129&showPromo=true`

Menu: `Home | Menu | Chief | Contact | Book Now`

i am new to WP and Elementor if its not possible then only solution  could be to use custom code to trigger custom popup with external link..

I was thing of using JavaScript/jQuery to monitor click event for menu item `Book Now` with class `book-now` so when user click on it, it will open custom menu.. this is a solution i can think of.

If there i an easy way of doing it do point in right direction.